# How to simplify this sum?

Tags: trigonometry, summation

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{\sin{(\frac{kj\pi}{n+1})}^2-\sqrt 2\sin{(\frac{k\pi}{n+1})}\sin{(\frac{kj\pi}{n+1})}}{1-2\cos{(\frac{k\pi}{n+1})}}$$
I think for rather a long time but I still could not figure out how to simplify. and because it comes from a question I'm trying solve, so $j$ is fixed, although it seems that it doesn't play any part here.
I have tried to convert $\sin$ to $\cos$ or unfold the $j$. But it doesn't   seem to work.
Is it possible that anybody help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does it come from something sensible?

Comment: The denominator is $\sin^2(k\pi / (n+1)$, that could be useful. Also, is $j$ fixed, or was that a typo?

Comment: Using `\sin` rather than `sin` will make your expression much more reasonable, and likewise for all trig functions and `\exp`, `\ln` etc

Comment: @GFauxPas I have edited the question.I'm new here...thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Reveillark yes,$j$ is fixed.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It actually come from the calculation of hitting time of metric.all these $\sin \cos$ are values of parameters.

Comment: hm can you prove the existence of such a sum?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner actually it comes from the calculation of some physical quantity.the formula is correct so such a sum is exist.

Comment: it gives many sums and we can not give an explicit sum for this

Comment: If $n+1$ is a multiple of $3$, we have a serious problem.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I originally suppose n may be random integer...can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Oh, simply that then for $k=(n+1)/3$, $1-2\cos \dfrac{k\pi}{n+1}=0$.